# How to insert nomenclature in the table of content

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX 2.3 (Document class: Koma-Script Book). I added nomenclature via insert>list/TOC>Nomenclature. I need to get nomenclature appeared in the table of content. I added the following in the preamble:

```
\def\nompreamble{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
```

With the above command, I am getting the nomenclature in the table of content; however in pdf bookmark, Nomenclature is showing under List of Tables.

[image]

Would anyone please suggest how to make it appeared like below?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: KOMA-Script package `scrhack` provides the `nomencl` hack. With this hack AFAIK the `listof=totoc` option of KOMA-Script classes not only adds the LoF and LoT to the table of contents but also the nomenclature. But I'm not a LyX user, so I cannot tell you, how to load the package.

Comment: For a bookmark to start at root, you may have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571952/234654), with `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` from the `bookmark` package.

Comment: Another point is, that with book classes all lists should be chapters. With using `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{…}` you also use a sublevel below the chapter level of the LoT. So `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{…}` could be a better choice.

Comment: @cabohah, many thanks. Your last comment worked for me.